# Prove: Every permutation matrix is the product of elementary matrices of interchanges (no replacement or scaling)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

I know that a permutation matrix is made up of standard basis vectors, but I'm not exactly sure how to put this in words.

Comment: this is designed for an inductive proof.  Do you know how to multiply block matrices?  (in particular multiply simple block diagonal matrices)

Comment: No, I don't :( We've only just finished learning about matrix inverses such as with the invertible matrix theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The symmetric group is generated by the transpositions.  Then use the homomorphism between the permutation matrices and the symmetric group.

Comment: I have not learned the word symmetric group or homomorphism. I'm trying to understand this from my undergrad Linear Algebra class.

Comment: I suggest that you have a look to a proof that the symmetric group is generated by the transpositions, even if you haven’t learned it. Because this is exactly the same thing that what you’re requested to do.